# how to stop(or terminate ) MPI_Recv after some perticular time when there is deadlock in MPI?

Tags: linux, gcc, mpi

I am trying to detect deadlocks in MPI

is there any method in which we can jump from function like MPI_Recv  after particular time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPI_Recv is a blocking function and will just sit there untill it receives the data it is waiting for, so if you are looking to have it timeout and error if things lock up then I don't think that's the one for you.

You could look into using [`MPI_Irecv`](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Irecv.3.php), which is the non-blocking version. You could then emulate the blocking behaviour of `MPI_Recv` using [`MPI_Wait`](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Wait.3.php) or [`MPI_Test`](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Test.3.php).

If you use a combination of `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Test` you could make a snippet that waits to recieve for a specified length of time, then errors if it hasn't. Rough example:

```
MPI_Irecv(..., &request); //start a receive request, non-blocking
time_t start_time = time(); //get start time
MPI_Test(&request, &gotData, ...); //test, have we got it yet

//loop until we have received, or taken too long
while (!gotData && difftime(time(),start_time) < TIMEOUT_TIME) {
  //wait a bit.
  MPI_Test(&request, &gotData, ...); //test again
}

//By now we either have received the data, or taken too long, so...
if (!gotData) { 
  //we must have timed out
  MPI_Cancel(&request);
  MPI_Request_free(&request);
  //throw an error
}
```

Comment: One should properly cancel unmatched non-blocking receives. I've modified your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev, I should have mentioned the need to add some clean up code.